# Error in Spring bean injection : leads to a NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am totally new to Spring framework, bean injections etc, and working on a project organized in many sub-projects about it.

In the *commons* subproject, containing all Entities, DAOs, DS, I have a `MyDS` class implementing `IMyDS` and containing its EntityManager and DAO :

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="myPersistenceUnit")
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("myDAO")
private IMyDAO mainDao;
```

Then, I am trying to call this class from the *Web* part of my project, like this:

```
@Autowired
private IMyDS myDS; 

// then I try to call a function of IMyDS, and get an error at this line :

protected ActionForward executeAction(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ReefPresentationException {
    myDS.callFunction(form);
}
```

But it doesn't work, giving me a *NullPointerException*. So far I've guessed the bean is not correctly injected, so I tried to add some information in my `application-context-spring.xml` file :

```
<bean id="myDS" class="com.my.project.service.IMyDS" />
```

And I get this error :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDS' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/application-context-spring.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.my.project.service.IMyDS]: Specified class is an interface

So I tried instead to declare the class :

```
<bean id="myDS" class="com.my.project.service.internal.MyDS" />
```

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDS' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/application-context-spring.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

So I really have no idea of what is wrong right now...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Show us your `MyDS` class.. Spring is telling it can't initialize that class.

Answer (score 1):

The errors says it all. You have defined your interface IMyDS as a bean and Spring can't instantiate the interface.